# Badminton Racket Sleeves

Tags: equipment, badminton

Buying a badminton racket is easy. Buying the right one is far more difficult. Each time when you buy a new racket however, the new racket is accompanied by a racket sleeve. I always threw them away, because they occupied space in my sports bag.

Are those sleeves for show or do they serve a purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those of us with lots of clutter (shoes, water bottles, pens, etc) knocking about in the racket bag it can protect the frame from chips and the strings from becoming snagged on anything loose.

For those without racket bags it provides the only protection from everything.

Someone once suggested that it also provides protection from extremes of hot and cold, which might cause the racket to play differently for a while.